# Bring window to front with Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.mac

I have a window that uses FileSystemWatcher to pop up when a new file is created. How can I get it to actually display / become the foreground window? MakeKeyAndOrderFront doesn't make it pop up infront of other windows.

Answer (score 2):

To make my window appear front, centered and focused I have had success with the following:

```
NSApplication app = NSApplication.SharedApplication;
app.ActivateIgnoringOtherApps(true);

var win = new PreferencesWindowController().Window;
win.Center();
win.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
```